# How get value of data in form-data in postman with empty key

Tags: api, laravel-5.8

How could I get the value of postman that has not key ...
when I use $request->all() or INPUT::get() in my controller they return null for me...
Is it possible by empty key???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrong. You should use like that :  [image]

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way according to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the value you are trying to send is in JSON format. The proper approach you need is to send the JSON in the body of the request. Here are the steps to take in Postman.

- Set key = `Content-Type` and value = `application/json` in the `Headers` section
- Choose the `Body` option and then `raw`

[image: Postman-Content-Type]

[image: Postman-Json-Body]